# Algorithm for distributing tasks to two printers?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, distribution

I am doing the programming exercise online, and I found this question:

> Two printers work in different speed. The first printer produces one paper in `x` minutes, while the second does it in `y` minutes. To print `N` papers in total, how to distribute the tasks to those printers so the printing time is minimum?

The exercise gives me three inputs `x`,`y`,`N` and asks for the minimum time as output.

> input data:
>
> 1 1 5
>
> 3 5 4
>
> answer:
>
> 3 9

I have tried to set tasks for first printer as `a`, and the tasks for the second printer as `N-a`. The most efficient way to print is to let them have the same time, so the minimum time would be ((n*b)/(a+b))+1. However this formula is wrong.

Then I tried to use a brute force way to solve this problem. I first distinguished which one is smaller (faster) in `a` and `b`. Then I keep adding one paper to the faster printer. When the time needed for that printer is longer than the time to print one paper of the other printer, I give one paper to the slower printer, and subtract the time of faster printer.

The code is like:

```
def fastest_time (a, b, n):
""" Return the smalles time when keep two machine working at the same time.
    The parameter a and b each should be a float/integer referring to the two
    productivities of two machines. n should be an int, refering to the total 
    number of tasks. Return an int standing for the minimal time needed."""

    # Assign the one-paper-time in terms of the magnitude of it, the reason 
    # for doing that is my algorithm is counting along the faster printer.
    if a > b:
        slower_time_each = a
        faster_time_each = b
    
    elif a < b :
        slower_time_each = b
        faster_time_each = a
    
    # If a and b are the same, then we just run the formula as one printer
    else :
        return (a * n) / 2 + 1
    
    faster_paper = 0
    faster_time = 0
    slower_paper = 0

    # Loop until the total papers satisfy the total task
    while faster_paper + slower_paper < n:
    
        # We keep adding one task to the faster printer
        faster_time += 1 * faster_time_each
        faster_paper += 1
    
        # If the time is exceeding the time needed for the slower machine,
        # we then assign one task to it
        if faster_time >= slower_time_each:
            slower_paper += 1
            faster_time -= 1 * slower_time_each

    # Return the total time needed
    return faster_paper * faster_time_each
```

It works when `N` is small or `x` and `y` are big, but it needs a lot of time (more than 10 minutes I guess) to compute when `x` and `y` are very small, i.e. the input is `1 2 159958878`.

I believe there is an better algorithm to solve this problem, can anyone gives me some suggestions or hints please?

Comment: check the indentation on your function

Comment: @anttihaapala thanks, fixed

Comment: Can you give an example of a slow input

Comment: @anttiHaapala you mean the inputs my program can't handle? Like 1 2 159958878

Comment: Outright one can see that the end value is wrong. For example, given 4 and 7 and N = 2, the time needed to print is 7, not anything related to the faster speed.

Comment: @attihappala oh you are right, I did not consider this situation. It becomes more difficult for me now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the input in form

```
x, y, n = 1, 2, 159958878
```

this should work

```
import math
math.ceil((max((x,y)) / float(x+y)) * n) * min((x,y))
```

This works for all your sample inputs.

```
In [61]: x, y, n = 1,1,5

In [62]: math.ceil((max((x,y)) / float(x+y)) * n) * min((x,y))
Out[62]: 3.0

In [63]: x, y, n = 3,5,4

In [64]: math.ceil((max((x,y)) / float(x+y)) * n) * min((x,y))
Out[64]: 9.0

In [65]: x, y, n = 1,2,159958878

In [66]: math.ceil((max((x,y)) / float(x+y)) * n) * min((x,y))
Out[66]: 106639252.0
```

**EDIT:**

This does not work for the case mentioned by @Antti i.e. `x, y, n = 4,7,2`.

Reason is that we are considering smaller time first. So the solution is to find both the values i.e. considering smaller time and considering larger time, and then choose whichever of the resultant value is smaller.

So, this works for all the cases including @Antii's

```
min((math.ceil((max((x,y)) / float(x+y)) * n) * min((x,y)),
     math.ceil((min((x,y)) / float(x+y)) * n) * max((x,y))))
```

Although there might be some extreme cases where you might have to change it a little bit.

Comment: Thank you! I am kinda confused about why we could choose to compute along the smaller time or the bigger time? I can think in this formula, but somehow I cannot reasoning it. Is it like assigning `r` papers to first printer and `n-r` papers to the second. Our first goal is to make them have the equal time, i.e. `ar = b (n-r)`, then we get r = (bn/(a+b)). Before times the corresponding time, why do we use ceiling function rather than floor function?

Comment: Here we use time taken by a printer to print 1 paper as proportion of the work done by one printer. It's like if `x,y=4,7`, then we can say, X printer will do y/(x+y) work and Y printer do x/(x+y) work. Now normally it is x/(x+y) for X and y/(x+y) for Y but here as these values are for time taken and we will be calculating work done which will be more if time is less so we reverse this the way we did. And, ceiling function is used because if how many papers printed by printer is 2.3 then basically it will print 3 papers and the other printer will rest for that .7 paper.